# VS2010 debugger - app won't launch properly, exit code 16

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++

I have a VS2010 express solution with two projects inside... one is a standalone app and the other is a VST2 plugin. For some reason I can no longer run either the app or the plugin (launching a vst2 host app) from the VS2010 debugger. The binaries launch fine on their own, just not from inside VS2010. Anyone know what might have changed in my project?

Both programs exit with the same message: The program has exited with code 16 (0x10).

the VS Debug output says something like this:

```
'vsthost.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Vsthost\vsthost.exe', Binary was not built with debug information.
```

... loads of dlls that don't have a PDB file

```
'vsthost.exe': Loaded 'C:\Documents and Settings\Oli Larkin\Local Settings\Temp\PIL77.tmp', Binary was not built with debug information.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xb24) has exited with code 16 (0x10).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x54c) has exited with code 16 (0x10).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x86c) has exited with code 16 (0x10).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3ec) has exited with code 16 (0x10).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x59c) has exited with code 16 (0x10).
The program '[3152] vsthost.exe: Native' has exited with code 16 (0x10).
```

Comment: Check your debugger settings, ensure the "Working directory" setting is blank or a valid directory.

Comment: I solved the problem - It was to do with the DigiDesign ASIO driver which was being loaded by both vsthost.exe and my app.exe. DigiDesign libraries refuse to play nicely with the MSVC debugger. Maybe due to some PACE related issue. I uninstalled the "Avid HD Driver" in control panel and now I can debug again.

thanks for your replies

Comment: Kinda makes sense, these kind of audio libraries have strong copy protection and anti-reverse engineering countermeasures.

Answer (score 1):

Start debugging normally using F10 and see where does it go.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem - It was to do with the DigiDesign ASIO driver which was being loaded by both vsthost.exe and my app.exe. DigiDesign libraries refuse to play nicely with the MSVC debugger. Maybe due to some PACE related issue. I uninstalled the "Avid HD Driver"